# Why is this function still lacking a return value?

Tags: java, function, ide, return

Suppose I write the function

```
public static Object create(int num) {
    if (num < 0 || num > 0) return null;
    if (num == 0) return new Object();
}
```

I have specified a return value (either `null` or a new object) for all possible integers (the `num < 0` case, the `num > 0` case, and the `num == 0` case).

Why, then, is my IDE telling me the function lacks a return value?

Answer (score 0):

IDE does not have to know that you have covered all integers. So as a compiler.
What it does know is that you have used constructions in your method that, by its definition, are not obligatory to be executed.